# What is the best way in jQuery to wrap elements based on its data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, algorithm

Given the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li data-conference="Conference1" >Spain</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference1" >France</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference1" >Germany</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference1" >Italy</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference2" >Austria</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference2" >Poland</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference3" >Russia</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference3" >USA</li>
    <li data-conference="Conference3" >China</li>
</ul>
```

what is the best way (with jQuery), considering performance, to rearrange this into this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Spain</li>
    <li>France</li>
    <li>Germany</li>
    <li>Italy</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Austria</li>
    <li>Poland</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Russia</li>
    <li>USA</li>
    <li>China</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? (except of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10470524/601179)...) What are the options you want us to decide?

Comment: If you consider performance, do you also consider vanilla js solutions? jQuery is a performance killer compared to vanilla js.

Comment: What is the logic to separate one ul in multiple ?

Comment: Best in terms of what? Best compared to what? Do you want us to compete?

Comment: @gdoron I didn't try cause I don't know how to do it.. that's why I am asking

Comment: @Sheikh I think thats clear no?

Comment: @Felix best in terms of performance..

Comment: Probably because you didn't show any effort in solving this yourself. The down vote quick info says: *This question does not show any research effort*.

Comment: @FelixKling. And because he is asking what is the best, while the OP don't have any basic option. So it's _"give me the best code you can"_ kind of question.

Comment: @Jonas. You should break that task to small pieces, start with one group only. If have problems with, ask again, show us what you have tried, And we will like to help you if we can.

Comment: @gdoron sorry if I hurt your feelings..

Comment: @Jonas. You didn't, I'll be happy to help you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the overall question (group elements by attribute) is good, you just should have put more effort into trying to solve it yourself.

Anyways, grouping elements by an attribute is quite simple. You can create an `attribute value -> [element, ...]` map, which can be done with an object:

```
var groups = {};

$('li[data-city]').each(function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-city'),
        group = groups[attr];
    if(!group) {
        group = groups[attr] = [];
    }
    group.push(this);
});
```

Now you have a collection of lists of DOM elements. You can iterate over the collection and create the HTML lists accordingly.

For example:

```
for(var group in groups) {
    var $list = $('<ul />');
    $list.append(groups[group]);
    // now append $list somewhere
}
```

Have a look at [*Working with Objects* <sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to get more information about how to process objects.

It's also trivial to do this without jQuery, as long as you have references to the elements, for example as a `NodeList`. Instead of using `.each` you can then use a "normal" `for` loop to iterate that list.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a insane amount of cities in those lists I wouldn't worry about performance.  The only performance consideration I would take is to avoid repaint / reflows by minimizing writing to the DOM.  I think code clarity is much more important in this use case.

That being said I'd implement this with something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/XWufy/.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(function () {
    var $list = $( '#list' );
    var lists = {};
    var $newLists = $();

    $list.children().each( function () {
        var city = $( this ).data( 'city' );
        if ( !lists[ city ] ) lists[ city ] = [];
        lists[ city ].push( this );
    });

    $.each( lists, function ( city, items ) {
        var $newList = $( '<ul />' ).append( items );
        $newLists = $newLists.add( $newList );
    });

    $list.replaceWith( $newLists );            
}());
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rjt9W/6/

Btw, the code assumes that the list has an ID of `"list"`. Replace the selector in this line

```
var $list = $( ... );
```

so that it properly selects your UL element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data attribute as an object property to sort them, then loop over them to construct the new html. this should get you started:

```
var list = {};
// for each item
list[item.data('city')] = item.text();

// for each property of list
var ul = $('<ul>');
// for each listItem in current list
var li = $('<li>').text(listItem);
ul.append(li);
```

Comment: @ParthThakkar his desired output does not have data attributes on the list items.

Comment: The aim is just to group the items based on the data attribute. No specific order needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = [];
var $div = $('#my_container_div');

$('li[data-city]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), data = $this.attr('data-city');
   list[ data ] = list[ data ] || [];
   list[ data ].push( $this.text() );
});

for(var data in list) {
   var $ul = $div.append('<ul/>');
   for(var li in list[data]) {
      $ul.append('<li>' + list[data][li] + '</li>');
   }
}
```

Comment: `var a = []; a[] = 'foo';` throws *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]"* for me in Chrome. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: ohk....sorry!!!!! extremely stupid of me....i took the thing wrongly...even the test i did before posting the bold comment was different....hadn't been more shameful than this!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ul id="first"></ul>// you can create the ul tags by using JavaScript

$("li").each(function(){
      data  = $(this).attr("data");
      if (data == "Conference1") {
         txt = $(this).text();
         $("<li>" + txt + "</li>").appendTo("ul#first");
      }
})
```